# OnSuccess method working after OnException method happened !! (PostSharp)

Tags: logging, attributes, postsharp, custom-attribute, log4postsharp

I am using PostSharp to making custom attributes that handling method logging , then write it in database table .

every thing it's working fine , but OnSuccess working every time ! even when i have an exception !!
my thought about OnSuccess is : working only if there is no Exception !

am i doing something wrong ?

```
public class Program
{
    static void  Main(string[] args)
    {

        MOHE.Program.Test test = new MOHE.Program.Test();
        Log x = new Log();
        test.testmethod(111 , 222 , "AAA");

    }
}
```

and this is mt Test Class :

```
public class Test
{
    [LogAttribute]
    public int testmethod(int x , int y , string z)
    {
        if (x == 2)
            x = 5;

        else throw new Exception("Exception");

        return x; 

    }
```

and this is my custom attribute :

```
[Serializable]
public sealed class LogAttribute : PostSharp.Aspects.OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{

    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        Logger logger = new Logger();
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;

        string Parameters = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < args.Method.GetParameters().Length; i++)
        {
            Parameters += args.Arguments[i].ToString() + " , ";
        }


        Log LOG = new Log
        {
            LogMassg = " Method Entry ",
            LogStatus = 1,
            LogType = 1,
            CreatedDate = dateTime,
            InputParameters = Parameters,
            MethodName = (args.Method.Name).ToString(),
            ClassName = (args.Method.DeclaringType).ToString(),
        };

        logger.AddLog(LOG);

        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Entering {0}.{1}.",
        args.Method.DeclaringType.Name, args.Method.Name), LOG.LogMassg);

    }



    public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        Logger logger = new Logger();
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;

        string Parameters = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < args.Method.GetParameters().Length; i++)
        {
            Parameters += args.Arguments[i].ToString() + " , ";
        }

        Log LOG = new Log
        {
            LogMassg = " Exception ",
            LogStatus = 2,
            LogType = 4,
            CreatedDate = dateTime,
            InputParameters = Parameters,
            MethodName = (args.Method.Name).ToString(),
            ClassName = (args.Method.DeclaringType).ToString(),

        };

        logger.AddLog(LOG);

        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Exception {0}.{1}.",
        args.Method.DeclaringType.Name, args.Method.Name), LOG.LogMassg);

    }




    public override void OnSuccess(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        Logger logger = new Logger();
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;

        string Parameters = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < args.Method.GetParameters().Length; i++)
        {
            Parameters += args.Arguments[i].ToString() + " , ";
        }
        Log LOG = new Log
               {
                   LogMassg = " Method Execution Success ",
                   LogStatus = 1,
                   LogType = 4,
                   CreatedDate = dateTime,
                   InputParameters = Parameters,
                   ReturnValues = (args.ReturnValue ?? "Exception occurred").ToString(),
                   MethodName = (args.Method.Name).ToString(),
                   ClassName = (args.Method.DeclaringType).ToString(),

               };

        logger.AddLog(LOG);

        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Method Execution Success {0}.{1}.",
        args.Method.DeclaringType.Name, args.Method.Name), LOG.LogMassg);

    }



    public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        Logger logger = new Logger();
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;

        string Parameters = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < args.Method.GetParameters().Length; i++)
        {
            Parameters += args.Arguments[i].ToString() + " , ";
        }

        Log LOG = new Log
        {
            LogMassg = " Method Exit ",
            LogStatus = 1,
            LogType = 1,
            CreatedDate = dateTime,
            InputParameters = Parameters,
            ReturnValues = (args.ReturnValue ?? "Exception occurred").ToString(),
            MethodName = (args.Method.Name).ToString(),
            ClassName = (args.Method.DeclaringType).ToString(),
        };

        logger.AddLog(LOG);

        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Leaving {0}.{1}.",
        args.Method.DeclaringType.Name, args.Method.Name), LOG.LogMassg);
    }

}
```

Database records :

```
LogID   LogMassg    InputParameters     ReturnValues
97   Method Entry   111 , 222 , AAA     NULL
98   Exception  111 , 222 , AAA ,   NULL
99 Method Execution Success 111 , 222 , AAA ,   0       
100  Method Exit    111 , 222 , AAA ,   0
```

Comment: You're right that OnSuccess should be called only if there is no exception. And I cannot see error in your code. What is the version of PostSharp you're using?

Comment: One advice - in your OnExit method you can check for exception using `args.Exception != null` instead of `args.ReturnValue ?? ...`.